# How to get label legend when clicking on BarChart entry?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm trying the following behaviour:
 When clicking on bar chart entry, I'd like to get the coresponding legend label (SF Zoo or LA Zoo)[image: barchart example]

The code that builds the BarDataSet:

```
List<IBarDataSet> barDataSetList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Float>> entry : hashMapCategorySpending.entrySet()) {
    String category = entry.getKey(); // here category is either SF Zoo or LA Zoo
    List<Float> values = entry.getValue();
    List<BarEntry> valuesConverted = convertToBarEntryArray(values); // some utility function

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(valuesConverted, category); // create BarDataSet
    barDataSet.setColor(StatisticsCategoryFragment.categoryColorHashMap.getOrDefault(category, 0));
    barDataSetList.add(barDataSet);
}

/* Set data to chart */
BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSetList);
barData.setValueTextSize(12.5f);
barChart.setData(barData);
```

My problem is that when overriding `setOnChartValueSelectedListener` that I cannot convert `Entry e` to something useful:

```
 barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
                BarEntry barDataSet = (BarEntry) e; // Doesn't help at all 
                // I want to do something like e.getLegendLabel(); and it should return SF Zoo or LA Zoo
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You could take the info from the `Highlight h` object:

```
String category = barChart.getLegend().getEntries()[h.getDataSetIndex()].label;
```